# Упорядочивание автоматически созданных столбцов в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется WPF-ный DataGrid, который должен поддерживать отображение различных классов, и поэтому снабженный автоматически генерируемыми столбцами (объём отображаемый свойств заранее не известен).

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMappings" 
ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelManager.Mappings, Mode=TwoWay}" 
AutoGenerateColumns="True"
AutoGeneratingColumn="dgMappings_AutoGeneratingColumn" 
AutoGeneratedColumns="dgMappings_AutoGeneratedColumns"/>
```

В ItemsSource грида поступают данные различных derived-классов, например, класса B (описание классов упрощено):

```
public abstract class A
{ 
   public int Prop1 { get; set; }
}


public class B : A
{ 
   public int Prop2 { get; set; }
   public int Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

При поступлении в свойство ChannelManager.Mapppings экземпляров класса B, порядок отображения сгенерированных DataGrid столбцов такой :

```
|   Prop2    |   Prop3    |   Prop1   |
```

Задача - изменить порядок следования столбцов. Порядок должен быть таким: сначала - свойства базового класса, затем - свойства наследника:

```
|   Prop1    |   Prop2    |   Prop3   |
```

**Есть следующая мысль, которая, однако, меня не устраивает:**

В методе `dgMappings_AutoGeneratingColumn` организовать присвоение некого мета-тега на основе `PropertyDescriptor` каждого из свойств, а в методе `dgMappings_AutoGeneratingColumns` уже разбираться, кто чей наследник и принудительно изменять `DisplayIndex` каждого из столбцов. Для этого придётся реализовать некий `metaTagsOrderHelper`, который должен разрешать эту задачу.

```
void dgMappings_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{        
   var columnMetaTag =  ((PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor).ComponentType;
   /// помещаем в какое-то хранилище, потому что у DataGridColumn нет свойства Tag
   metaTagsOrderHelper.Add(e.Column, columnMetaTag);
}


void dgMappings_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   /// разбираемся в накопленных в хранилище метатегах
   foreach (var col in dgMappings.Columns)
   { 
     col.DisplayIndex = metaTagsOrderHelper.GetIndex(col);
   }
}
```

Этот способ кажется мне довольно корявым, существует ли более элегантное решение, позволяющее изменить порядок свойств на уровне внутреннего перечисления в DataGrid?

Comment: `Type.GetProperties()` возвращает свойства именно в таком порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше решение имеет право на жизнь и, в общем-то, достаточно простое в реализации.

Я, вместо подписки на `AutoGeneratingColumn`, предлагаю реагировать на изменение `ItemsSource`, это позволит в одном месте перебрать все свойства элемента коллекции и выбрать для них порядок следования.

У `DataGrid` нету свойства наподобие ItemsSourceChanged, поэтому я предлагаю задавать `DataContext` и подписываться на его изменения:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Items}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          DataContextChanged="DataGrid_DataContextChanged"
          AutoGeneratedColumns="DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns"/>
```

Теперь, при смене `DataContext` определяем тип элементов в коллекции, получаем список свойств элемента и сортируем их *по глубине наследования* (я так это обозвал):

```
Dictionary<string, int> PropOrder;

private void DataGrid_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var items = (IEnumerable<object>)e.NewValue;
    var type = items.GetType()
                    .GetGenericArguments()
                    .Single();
    var props = type.GetProperties()
                    .OrderByDescending(p => GetInheritanceDepth(type, p));
    var index = -1;
    PropOrder = props.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => ++index);
}
```

Глубина наследования вычисляется просто:

```
private int GetInheritanceDepth(Type type, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    if (propertyInfo.DeclaringType == type) return 0;
    return 1 + GetInheritanceDepth(type.BaseType, propertyInfo);
}
```

После того, как все столбцы сгенерированы, устанавливаем им порядок:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    foreach (var column in dataGrid.Columns)
        column.DisplayIndex = PropOrder[(string)column.Header];
}
```